# Simple Application for sending Keystroke in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I have an issue regarding Sendkeys Class, as i want to use this class in order to send some keystroke to the active application.
As a first step i want to test the {Enter} keystroke, so in order to achieve that i made a simple application in vb.net 2010

```
Public Class Form1
Public Shared data As String
Private Sub SendintText(command As String)
    Try
        SendKeys.SendWait(command)
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    data = TextBox1.Text.ToString
    SendingText(data)
End Sub
```

End Class

When i tried to run for {Enter} i have received infinit loop error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Could someone help me?

LATER EDIT : In meantime i have found another example

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

If in background i have two applications :

1. Visual Studio
2. Target application

How can i focus on the target application, because now when i am running the form , that form became active..is there any solution to call the winform from command prompt with some parameter (the key that i want to send)?

Later Edit2
**strong text**
i have give it up the idea for windows form, so finnally i have made a simple program in console application that simulates the keystroke ...                                           Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Module1

```
Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim data As String = args(0)
    Console.WriteLine("You insert the : {0}", data)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    SendKeys.SendWait(data)
End Sub
```

End Module

By the way in order to use double quotes in a parameter you need \"test\"...(i have spent 15 min to find out) so it might be usefull...
Thanks again for the informations.

Comment: when you click button, it gets focus. then what is the purpose of sending keys to button??

Comment: i 've just want to test a sending key (by entering that key in a textbox ) to an application...is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Of course you can do that. Have you looked? What did you search for?

Comment: i have give it up the idea, but finnally i have made a simple program in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sendkey to another application, you need to first activate that application on the button click and then send keys

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx)

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
    string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Send a series of key presses to the Calculator application.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
    // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
    IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame","Calculator");

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
    if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
    // a set of calculations.
    SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("111");
    SendKeys.SendWait("*");
    SendKeys.SendWait("11");
    SendKeys.SendWait("=");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, i have already read it before i post my question.

Comment: Also i have noticed that always when i am running this windows form application , the focus is on windows form even if i have another application open...

Comment: I couldn't get this working in VB.NET, as "SendWait is not a member of SendKeys". Any suggestions?

Comment: @LeoKing Did you reference System.Windows.Forms ?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Button has focus.  Button click event sends an enter keystroke. Sending an enter causes the button click event to fire. Infinite loop.

You could disable the button before and re-enable the button after the sendkeys routine is done to stop the infinite loop.

What you probably would want to do is switch the focus back to the application you want to send your keystrokes to.

Comment: i have tried with setting focus , but i have received the same error...maybe i am missing something...i 've just want to test a parametrization  sendkey ...this is the purpose of this simple application