# vb.net sendkeys to any active application

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

im trying to make a vb.net application that sendkeys to any application that I activate, but for beginners like me, i started using it on textbox. but my problem is after i click the start button to start the send keys, my application hangs. so here is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Text = "Start" Then
            Button1.Text = "Stop"
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Do While Button1.Text <> "Start"
                SendKeys.Send("{a}")
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Loop
        Else
            Button1.Text = "Start"
        End If
    End Sub
```

so the idea is if i press the button1, the text will change to "Stop" then it will focus on textbox1 then it will do loop and sendkeys until i press the stop. but i have no luck. hope someone can help me and add somecode that will work even i change the active windows and keep on sendkeys or keystroke. thx

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is hanging is because you are doing all of this within the one thread. A click happens, and the code above gets triggered within a single thread. When the `While` loop is entered, it sends the keys, then sleeps the entire thread for one second, then loops again, because the loop condition is still true.

What I recommend you do instead is set up a timer, running every 1000 milliseconds, then in that timer function, put something like the following code:

```
If Button1.Text <> "Start" Then
    SendKeys.Send("{a}")
End If
```

And then change your button click code to the much simpler:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Text = "Start" Then
            Button1.Text = "Stop"
            TextBox1.Focus()
        Else
            Button1.Text = "Start"
        End If
End Sub
```

This is changing to use two different event handlers, one for the button click, and one for the timer firing each time, which each get called when the appropriate thing happens. The rest of the time, your program is doing nothing, which is a good thing, as it doesn't waste resources.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789733/simple-application-for-sending-keystroke-in-vb-net) has an answer with a link to an MSDN article and also some sample code.  It should do what you want (long term).  In the short term to answer your 'why is it hanging question', you are "hanging" because you are in a loop on a single thread checking the value of the text field.